# What approaches can comply with SOX code review requirements?

Tags: corporate-law

I am working with a client, which has a bunch of services under SOX compliance.

They currently have a code-review policy that looks like so:

1. A reviewer *must* accept the *last* commit on a pull request

This means that if someone rebases, or makes a small nit change, they need to get a review all over again. This causes a velocity slowdowns.

The reason they do this is:

> SOX mandates that all Changes are tested and approved before being
>   deployed to Production. If a developer can make a change after a code
>   review, then we loose the assurance that code has been
>   reviewed/approved. The risk is that functionality might be altered
>   (intentionally or not) without Management awareness.

I am having trouble believing that this is the best solution for SOX compliance. Looking around at documentation for SOX, it doesn't specifically say that code review *needs* to look like this.

Are there better approaches? I would love to help my client increase their velocity here, without adding too much risk to SOX compliance

Comment: What’s the legal question here? The law is clear that the company must demonstrate compliance. How they demonstrate it is a business question, not a legal one.

Comment: Hey Dale, I think the question is: I am not sure what are the legal limits of "demonstration" here. i.e from a business perspective, I think it demonstrates enough to have 1 code review, without necc approving the latest commit. Perhaps that is not enough from a legal perspective